# Pythonic squeeze and unsqueeze data dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

For giving the data in good dimensions to a PyTorch Model, I use squeeze en unsqueeze function like this:

```
   inps = torch.FloatTensor(data[0])
   tgts = torch.FloatTensor(data[1])
   
   tgts = torch.unsqueeze(tgts, -1)
   tgts = torch.unsqueeze(tgts, -1)
   tgts = torch.unsqueeze(tgts, -1)
   inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, -1)
   inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, -1)
   inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, -1)
```

and this:

```
    inps = torch.FloatTensor(data[0])
    tgts = torch.FloatTensor(data[1])
      
    tgts = torch.unsqueeze(tgts, 1)
    tgts = torch.unsqueeze(tgts, 1)
    tgts = torch.unsqueeze(tgts, 1)
    inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, 1)
    inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, 1)
    inps = torch.unsqueeze(inps, 1)
```

But of course, I'm kinda embarrassed to have this repetitive part in my code. Is there another way, more pythonic and clean, to write this code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.Tensor.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html#torch-tensor-view) like below:

```
how_many_unsqueeze = 3
extra_dims = (1,) * how_many_unsqueeze
# extra_dims -> (1,1,1)

inps.view(-1, *extra_dims) # -> (-1,1,1,1)
tgts.view(-1, *extra_dims) # -> (-1,1,1,1)
```

You can use [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html#torch-reshape) like below:
*But after using like in your question you need back to original shape*

**Instead of unsqueeze**

```
inps = torch.reshape(inps, (len(data[0]),1,1,1))
tgts = torch.reshape(tgts, (len(data[1]),1,1,1))
```

**Instead of squeeze**

```
inps = torch.reshape(inps, (len(data[0]),))
tgts = torch.reshape(tgts, (len(data[1]),))
```

Comment: @l'mahdi Thank you so much for your answer. I just didn't get the sentence in italics: "But after using like in your question you need back to original shape". Could you please explain it a bit more.

Comment: @Totoro, welcome. In the second approach, I use reshaping and change the shape of the original tensor, and after using it we need to reshape like as the first, but in `view` approach we don't need back to original shape. you can print the `shape` of two approach at the end to understand

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to reshape you can also use indexing to do the same:

If we have

```
a = torch.zeros((4,5,1,1,1))
```

we can get

```
b = a[:, :, 0, 0, 0]  # shape (4, 5)
```

and

```
c = b[:, :, None, None, None] # shape (4, 5, 1, 1, 1)
```

Note that if you want to programmatically specify what dimensions to squeeze unsqueeze you can use tuples:

```
a[x,y,z]
```

is the same as

```
a[(x,y,z)]
```

so the last example could be written for instance as

```
idx = 2*[slice(None)] + 3*[None]
c = b[tuple(idx)]
```